# Usage of the phrase "for a change"

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we use the phrase "for a change" to make a sarcastic comment or insulting comment like

> Why don't we let her say this good news to others, for a change

Or

> You have made quite a good point, for a change

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be used sarcastically. It is fairly common. It implies that whatever you are suggesting is not common.

For example

> He had a good idea, for a change.

That implies that his ideas are not normally good.

Answer (score 3):

The examples in the question are perfectly fine "insulting comments," but they are not sarcasm.

The example in Gabriel's answer, while a correct usage, is also not sarcasm.  If the person's ideas are not normally good, then it is just a straightforward statement (His ideas are not normally good, but for a change, this one is).

One way to use "for a change" sarcastically is to apply it to something that is in fact common.

Let's say John always eats Chinese food for lunch.  One might say, "Hey, John, why don't I take you out for Chinese, for a change?"  This is sarcasm, because it would, in fact, not be a change for John to have Chinese food.