# Time for change verses time for a change

Tags: articles

> The legal system cannot protect the children; **it is time for change**.

versus

> I have been eating the same food for the last two years; **it is time for a change**.

I have seen both usages. To my ears, neither sounds ungrammatical. What is the difference? (My gut feeling is that **time for a change** implies *any* change, while the agent who expressed the former has some specific change in mind.)

Comment: There's not really any difference. But *It's time for **a** change* is the idiomatically established form (see [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88838/usage-of-the-phrase-for-a-change)). You'll normally only hear the article-less form as a "soundbite / campaign slogan" from politicians (in particular, I think Obama was keen on it).

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, and in the examples the meaning is very similar. "Time for change" implies a general or broad change, and perhaps implies that change is needed but the speaker is not saying what change. "Time for a change" more often is used with a specific proposal, but can also be used for the general case. Often there will be little difference of meaning between the forms.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is 'a'.

We need to analyze only 'a'

The article 'a' has many usages including : 'a' is  used like any to refer in a general way to people or things" [https://dict.naver.com/enendict/#/entry/enen/d7290167a32945e39e0313fb39ecc6ac"](https://dict.naver.com/enendict/#/entry/enen/d7290167a32945e39e0313fb39ecc6ac%22)
A person who is sick can't work well. [=people can't work well if they are sick]

Time for change means just 'change' and 'Time for a change' means any/some change.

To my ears (as a non-native English speaker), '"Time for 'a' change" sounds like 'this time is a right time for any change or we need any/some change now'

And without 'a' it might also mean an overblown expression (not specific but just 'change' like "Gentlemen, this is the time for change."

I believe 'change' is broader than 'a change'.